# App rejected due to UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store, apple-developer

I just developed an iOS app which is used WebView features by Flutter framework and after several submitting to upload it into App Store, it was rejected due to Accurate Metadata which the reviewer mentioned UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key is set in way that we could not install in on iPad running iOS 15.4.1. I wonder how can I manage to fix it!. What I have done yet is, firstly leaving out this key by removing it in Info.plist file. Secondly, Setting UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to armv7. Moreover I tested my app on serveral iOS and iPad simulators without any problem and my Xcode version is 13.

I am looking forward that anybody can help me to tackle this issue.

Here is the content of my Info.plist file in iOS folder.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>***</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>***</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>***</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
      <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What was the value(s) in UIResuiredDeviceCapabilities ? Did you have arm64 ?

Comment: You need to test a TestFlight build on real devices.  Simulators are ok for development, but they are not a substitute

Comment: No, there is only a single value armv7 there! @PtitXav

Comment: Do you have the iPad orientations set ?

Comment: Dear @PtitXav, I put the content of my Info.plist file. please look it up.

Comment: You may have one clue [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/98481)

Comment: @PtitXav May the problem is related to Internet or camera permission, because I am used WebView browsers in my app?

Comment: @Paulw11 Unfortunately, I unable to access actual devices to test a TestFlight build.